# Update message and Outlook Web caching?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When using the Update message API from Microsoft Graph (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_update) to update the body of an email, although the API succeeds and you can see in the preview of the email in the Outlook web interface that the new body has been applied you cannot see the new body in the full message until you completely refresh the page. It seems that the web interface downloads the preview and the full body of the message from different places. Any tips on how to make the Outlook web pick the new message without a refresh?

Answer (score 0):

The API take the preview and the full body of the message from the same place. But we will not refresh the full page by default(Ajax). So we just see the preview content. We cannot do that without a refresh, but I think we maybe do it without significant refresh(ajax to replace page content too, still trying)

Comment: Thanks for the update, is there an issue for this work that I can follow to be notified about its release?

Comment: I have not saw a official state on your question. So we just can try to achieve it by ourself now. Of course, you can submit a feature request in the uservoice:https://officespdev.uservoice.com/